Storing memory of 14kB and cells 1byte
Welcome! I have a theoretical question.
How many bits would be needed to address 14kB of case data memory if one cell is 1 byte in size?
My answer would be, 14kB is 14,336 bytes and would require that many memory cells. And the result should be 114,688 bits... right?

If you mean address bits you’d need 14 bits to address up to 16384 bytes of memory. 13 bits could only address up to 8192 bytes. Compute with log(#bytes)/log(2)


14kB is 14,336 bytes and would require that many memory cells

It would, but that's not the question, the question was:

How many bits would be needed to address 14kB of case data memory if one cell is 1 byte in size

I don't know what "case" is supposed to mean in that sentence, but apart from that it's a question about how many bits are needed to address the memory, not how many bits is the size of the memory itself.
So, take the base 2 logarithm of however many addressable cells you have, and round up.

okey, it turns out 14 bits will be needed. Right?

@Kito looks good to me

8 bit = 1 byte and
1024 byte = 1 kb.
14 kb ---> 1024 * 14 byte and
14 kb ---> 1024 * 14 * 8 bit
